# Why is Azure Storage API permission not listed in azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to build an [app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55352689/2715229) that accesses the azure storage API using AAD credentials, I noted that some API permissions are not listed within the azure portal and the only way to set them is through editing the app registration manifest directly. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55415011/2715229) for more details.

[image]

**My question is simple:**

1. Did I miss the permission for `user_impersonation` on Azure Storage in the portal or is it truly not listed?
2. If so, where can we find a complete list of all available permissions with its GUIDs so configuring the manifest manually is easier?

For instance I found the correct GUID for `user_impersonation` on Azure Storage somewhere on a internet forum and added it to my manifest as shown below.

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
    "resourceAppId": "e406a681-f3d4-42a8-90b6-c2b029497af1",
    "resourceAccess": [
        {
            "id": "03e0da56-190b-40ad-a80c-ea378c433f7f",
            "type": "Scope"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The result hover can be seen in the portal after modification of the manifest:

[image]

Comment: Please click on "APIs my organization uses" (next to "Microsoft APIs") and there you'll see Azure Storage.

Comment: thanks @GauravMantri but even there it is not showing up: https://imgur.com/nCVol9G 
I've tried many search strings but no results. Is it visible in your tenant this way?

Comment: Hmm....Weird. I am assuming you're using `App Registration (Preview)` to register your app. This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrX16.png.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri - I've tested it again and found out that the search in that dialog is not finding anything (what ever you search for). Having said that, it is a bug in my opinion. After scrolling manually through the list and "load more", I was able to find the entry. I've added this finding as an answer to my own question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the entry should be visible unter "**APIs my organization uses**".

*However*, the search there is not returning anything, which seems to be a temporary bug.

You have to manually scroll through the list and hit "load more". From there you'll find Azure Storage as an API permission.

[image]

Comment: Currently, I can't see them either but I can't even see a "load more..", any idea why?

Comment: Hi @Mese, I quickly checked, and I can see the "load more" button. I clicked it a couple of times, and I can see Azure Storage in the list. Please clear your browser cache or try a different one. If nothing helps, edit the manifest manually as I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55415011/2715229